# Spring MVC HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My Item Object

```
public class Item extends MyBaseObject {

    private String          name;
    private Category        category;
    private ItemType        itemType;
    private String          description;
    private Long            reorderLevel;
    private Long            freezeLevel;
    private Set<Inventory>  inventories = new TreeSet<>();
    private long            totalCount;
    private long            currentlyIssued;
    private long            availableStock;

    ... getter and setters
}
```

itemAdd.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/common/head.jsp" />

<h2 class="demoHeaders">Item (Add New)</h2>

<form:form id="frmItemAdd" method="post" modelAttribute="item">
    <table class="vsform">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="name"><spring:message code="item.name"></spring:message></form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="name" class="inputlarge required"/>
                    <form:errors path="name" class="errorMsg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="description"><spring:message code="item.description"></spring:message></form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:textarea path="description" rows="5" cols="50" class="inputlarge"/>
                    <form:errors path="description" class="errorMsg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="category"><spring:message code="item.category"></spring:message></form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="category" class="myform inputlarge">
                        <form:options items="${listCategory}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
                    </form:select>
                    <form:errors path="category" class="errorMsg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="itemType"><spring:message code="item.itemType"></spring:message></form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="itemType" class="myform inputlarge">
                        <form:options items="${listItemType}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
                    </form:select>
                    <form:errors path="itemType" class="errorMsg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="reorderLevel"><spring:message code="item.reorderLevel"></spring:message></form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="reorderLevel" class="inputsmall required"/>
                    <form:errors path="reorderLevel" class="errorMsg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="freezeLevel"><spring:message code="item.freezeLevel"></spring:message></form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="freezeLevel" class="inputsmall required"/>
                    <form:errors path="freezeLevel" class="errorMsg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button id="buttonReset" type="reset">Reset</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="buttonSubmit">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>

<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/common/foot.jsp" />
```

My controller ItemAddController

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/ims/item/addNew")
public class ItemAddController extends InventoryBaseController {

    @Autowired
    private InventoryService inventoryService;

    @Autowired
    private ItemAddValidator itemAddValidator;

    @ModelAttribute("listCategory")
    public List<Category> getListCategory(){
        return inventoryService.listCategory();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("listItemType")
    public List<ItemType> getListItemType(){
        return inventoryService.listItemType();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String itemAdd(Model model, RedirectAttributes reat, Principal principal){

        Item item = new Item();

        model.addAttribute("item", item);
        return "manager/item/itemAdd";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String itemAdd(@ModelAttribute Item item, Model model, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes reat, Principal principal){
        this.itemAddValidator.validate(item, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            return "manager/item/itemAdd";
        }

        item.setAddDefaults(principal.getName());
        if (this.inventoryService.addItem(item)){
            reat.addFlashAttribute("message", "Item record added successfully.");
        } else {
            reat.addFlashAttribute("message", "Item record not added.");
        }
        return "redirect:/ims/item/addNew";
    }
}
```

The crux of the problem is that when I am feeding the correct values for each field the form submission works properly. But when I am giving 'a' or any text value for form field reorderLevel (which is defined as Long) the browser throws this error : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

I have already defined the following in messages.properties file:

```
typeMismatch=Could not convert to the required type.
typeMismatch.java.util.Calendar=Please enter date in the dd-MM-yyyy format.
typeMismatch.java.math.BigDecimal=Please enter value in correct format 0.00
typeMismatch.java.lang.Long=Must specify an integer value.
```

Please help... Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853714/spring-usage-of-typemismatch-messages?

Comment: Problem solved the order ModelAttribute Item item, Model model, BindingResult result,... should be replaced with ModelAttribute Item item, BindingResult result, Model model,...  The BindingResult should be placed immediately after the Object we are passing through the form. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: This post really helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399101/spring-http-status-400-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorr