# typeMismatcch sting to long binding exception

Tags: spring-mvc

My set up is Spring 4.25 and hibernate validator 4.3 
I have a form that has a string , in the model its a Long. I ??.properties file with many typeMismatch = user friendly message or  typeMismatch.amount=another user friendly message

why am I unable to pick up the 'user friendly message' instead I get a Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long] for property 'amount'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dfg".

Do I need a custompropertyeditor ?

I can't make any sense?

Regards,
jemrug

Comment: Take a look here: [Spring usage of typeMismatch messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853714/spring-usage-of-typemismatch-messages)

Comment: My problem is odd. I have a jsp which only has message part. I use  currentError.getDefaultMessage to get at the error message, this returns a null. [ static void processErrors(final BindingResult result, final MultiViewJsonFactory factory) {

        final List<String> errorsList = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (ObjectError currentError : result.getAllErrors()) {
            errorsList.add(currentError.getDefaultMessage());
        }